# Update access recordset using VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

How do I update an MS-Access recordset using VB.NET?

I've basically to update a field which has id of 1, and field value for 'ticker' is 'UKX'.

The data to be updated is in the 'value' field and comes from a Public Sub. dLast is the data which I need inputting to update the current value.

I've currently got the code:

```
Function update_db()
    ' need to update the database
    Dim daoengine As DAO.DBEngine
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    daoengine = New DAO.DBEngine
    dbs = daoengine.OpenDatabase("Project.mdb")
    rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("ftsedata", DAO.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)
    rst.Edit()
    ' what do I do here to edit the field "value" where ticker=UKX ?
    rst.Close()
    dbs.Close()
End Function

Public Sub getftsestock()
    Dim sAPIUrl As String = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=UKX"
    Dim oDocument As XDocument = XDocument.Load(sAPIUrl)
    Dim dLast As Double = CDbl(GetData(oDocument, "last"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your sub into a function like so

```
Public function getftsestock() as double
    Dim sAPIUrl As String = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=UKX"
    Dim oDocument As XDocument = XDocument.Load(sAPIUrl)
    getftsestock = CDbl(GetData(oDocument, "last"))
End Sub
```

Then do your update like this

```
    rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("select * from ftsedata where (ticker='UKX')", DAO.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)
    while not rsy.eof
        rst.Edit
        rst("value").value = getftsestock()
        rst.update

       rst.movenext
    wend

   rst.Close()
```

However, it would be much more efficient to do this.

```
daoengine.Execute "Update ftsedata SET value='" & getftsestock() & "' WHERE ticker='UKX'"
```

Comment: How would I apply the value from dLast from getftsetock()?

Comment: Ah, many thanks - clears that up - didn't know it was stored that way. VB2008Express likes to remove my Set keyword. I'll put them back in.

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed that it was VB.NET. I assumed it was VBA because you are using DAO/Access. You don't need the SET statements if it is VB.NET only VB6 and VBA

Comment: For rst("value") = getftsestock(), it says the property 'Item' is read-only.

Comment: Try adding the .value property and it may help, if that doesn't work tweak the recordset type, also make sure that table has a primary key defined or you can't edit it.  In any event, I strongly suggest using the alternative I provided, it is a much better way of doing this than using a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call Execute method of Database object.

```
daoengine.Execute "Update TableName set Col1=Value1 Where Ticker='UKX'"
```

You should have to use ADO.NET `Oledb` provider instead of `DAO` in VB.NET.